# Pineapple catastrophe!

Tags: pineapple

[image: pineapple plant]I have had this pineapple plant for almost 3 years now. Just in the last 6 months have I actually been able to see noticeable improvements of growth. It's at least 4 to 5 times the size it was 6 months ago. I know it has produced pineapples already - 3 to be exact. Why hasn't it produced a flower for me yet? What am I doing wrong with it? I wish I could find out exactly how old it is . Any suggestions/advice will be greatly appreciated. I live in USDA ZONE 7B AMD 8A.

Comment: You might be summering it out but wintering in a sunny window in those zones. What is the catastrophe? Flowers come before fruit, so whatever shoot or inflorescence appears before the baby pineapples, there's your flower thing. Don't expect a showy flower.

Comment: If it is growing fast, possibly it is ready to produce pineapple. Just wait more. Maybe start looking in the center, if you start seeing the flower buds growing

Answer (score 3):

Pineapples grow by producing a rosette of leaves like a Yucca, then send up a vertical spike with the fruit on top, followed by side shoots at top and bottom as vegetative reproduction outlets. Once the main crown has fruited the associated leaves and central stem die away to allow the side offshoots to take over. At this point the grower can interfere and ensure that only one strong offshoot persists to produce another fruit in its turn. If no-one takes action, multiple much smaller rosettes and fruit spikes may appear.

Since the old crown dies away what we may conclude in your case is that what you now have is a shoot that survived from the old crown. The old crown is long gone and now this one is next in line for fruiting.

As for growing area, think a location that is completely open on all sides so no shade, consistently hot and humid with lots of sunshine for long periods. Think Bahamas, Costa Rica, Florida, Hawaii, Caribbean, the tropics. The further you are from these ideal growing locations, the more often there are cold periods, particularly cold rain with poor sun exposure and you can double, quadruple, xtuple the length of time it will take to generate the internal chemistry to produce a new fruit. It may idle for long periods making no progress and then burst into life when conditions are right.

Up to you to comment whether your case mirrors this narrative.

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle of bromeliads is to flower, fruit and then slowly die while putting out offshoots or "pups".  They only set fruit [once](https://gardeningsolutions.ifas.ufl.edu/plants/edibles/fruits/pineapples.html).

If your plant has already fruited then you should look for signs of growth at the base of the plant as it sends out the pups.

Comment: If this plant has produced 3 pineapples in its life, does that mean at least 2 came from pups still on the mother?

Comment: @MackM a pineapple only produces one fruit in a lifetime.  I don't see any pups in the picture so the information we have is inconclusive